# Firebase as backend as well as front end

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to know if my approach of building a application is correct or if I am missing something,

[image]

I have my front end code host in Firebase and finally database use as Firebase itself. As I do so I couldn't find a place to put my business logic now then I planned to host it in separate server and expose it as Rest service. Actually like a middle-ware.

is there any way to overcome from this middle ware and host business logic also in Firebbase itself.

appreciate your suggession.
Please note that I want to do my development for free which is why Firebase suits me.

Comment: Look into Firebase cloud functions. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/.

Comment: I need to do it for free

Comment: This is available in the free tier.

Comment: I did some basic tutorials and it seems suite my need.Thanks.At the same time I need to know from that can I host my own node-js project where I am using express and all in my own MVC framework.do I need to follow any patterns that fire-base tutorials follows ?

Comment: The fundamental idea behind Firebase is that you don't need to have your own backend. That is why it is called "backend as a service". Cloud functions are designed to eliminate any possible reasons to need your own backend. No one is stopping you from writing one, of course, but what exactly do you need it for? It will add potentially unnecessary complexity to your stack.

Comment: Thing is that i have complex business logic in my node js project which i need to write freely (without follow firebase patterns) but only deploy there.Thanks for foreseen and inform the potential problems I may encounter in future.